# Access native windows icons for custom wxDialogs

Tags: python, user-interface, dialog, wxpython, customdialog

I want to subclass `wx.Dialog` to get a little more functionality than is provided by the `wx.MessageDialog` class but I would still like to be able to use the native windows icons (ie the ones used in the wx.MessageDialog that can be set by the flags such as `wx.ICON_ERROR` etc.. )

Is there anyway to access these?

**Update:**

Thanks to steven for pointing out that this can easily be accomplished with [wx.ArtProvider](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.ArtProvider-class.html)

*e.g.*

```
wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(wx.ART_ERROR, wx.ART_CMN_DIALOG)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(wx.ART_ERROR, wx.ART_CMN_DIALOG)
```

Comment: That is definitely a good trick:) (worked once I changed wx.ICON_ERROR to wx.ART_ERROR). Ive come across the ArtProvider class before but for some reason I thought it was GTK only. Just used it to get icons for all my menu items as well -very handy. Thanks!! –

Comment: Yup, I've used it to add icons to my menus that don't use standard wx IDs. I noticed how Windows never had icons in their menus so I only do it for GTK (not sure what mac does)

Comment: whoops I did have ART_ERROR originally but then copied/pasted your ID over :)

Comment: yes your right Iv noticed that two about windows menus, they look pretty though :) so its hard to resist adding them...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you'd do in in wx, but here's a Microsoft article on how to do it with the native API:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188763.aspx

Comment: Thanks for that...
but hopefully a  *pre cooked* solution exists, Id rather not have to go coding wrappers for the winapi (as Id imagine that is what I would have to do?)